# Pyinstaller giving error

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, python, executable

I am trying to deploy our python service into our test server, but I am facing an issue.

We are doing development on Rock Pi S board (yocto image OS) which has Python 3.7 and we accidentally developed the service using Python 3.8 (local), working fine in local system. Now I need to deploy the service to the test server. For that I am building (making .exe) the python file on the server which has Python 3.7 and while building it's giving the error which I mention below.

[image: Image of errors]

Additional Info :
OS - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Commands used for building the .exe:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
$ pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
$ pip3 install pyinstaller
$ pyinstaller --onefile pythonfile.py
```

How can I fix this problem?

I tried to upgrade python version on the OS level, but no support from the team (Yocto). Is it the difference in python version which is causing this issue?

Comment: please post text as text rather than as an image. Images are not searchable.

Comment: have you tried updating asyncio i.e. pip install asyncio --upgrade

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I tried. But still same issue and thanks for your suggestion.